# Upload Image With angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, image-upload

I am having issues in image upload in my file '../src/app/assets/'.I have this Form

```
 <form [formGroup]="formRegister" novalidate="">  
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputImage">Image</label>
        <input type="file" (change)="onFileSelect($event)" name="image" 
           class="form-control" placeholder="Enter votre image">
    </div>
</form>
<button type="button" (click)="onRegister()">Submit</button>
```

In my ts

```
formRegister: FormGroup;
errorMail: string = "";
selectedFile: File = null;

constructor(private appService: AppServiceService, private http: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.formRegister = new FormGroup({      
  image: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
});
}


onFileSelect(event) {
  console.log("event : ", event);
  this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
 }

onRegister(): void {
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('image', this.selectedFile);
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', '../src/app/assets/', fd);
this.http.request(req).subscribe(events => {
  console.log("Upload Image", events);
},
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log("Erreur : ", err.message);    // Show error, if any.
  });
}
```

In my console i have an errors :
http://localhost:4200/src/app/assets/ 404 (Not Found)

Where is the problem in my code and thanks.

Comment: You cannot `HTTP POST` a file to a folder, it must be to a server.

Comment: how can i put the image in my file? I want to install server? or to replace HTTP to another cmd?

Comment: If your intention is for the uploaded image to be available to everyone who visits your website then you must have a server to receive the request and save the file.

Comment: Do you have a tutorial for this idea?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to apply an image in folder with only angular. It is possible to convert the image in base64 and register in string.

When you want to apply image in folder it is necessary to use server (Node Js, spring boot ...)

And thanks